# Using Template Strings to get object property

Tags: angular

// why it dont give output as soni, Angular 2 using typescript

```
let u = { lastname: 'soni' };
    let xx = '${u.lastname}';
    console.log(xx);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the other single quote:

```
let xx = `${u.lastname}`;
```